# Time complexity to calculate the prime factorization of a large number

Tags: cryptography

I was wondering what is the best(least) approximate time that even the fastest computers take to find prime factors of a very large integer, eg. $2000$ bit-integer, since it has various implications in cryptography for example the RSA algorithm.

Comment: For general input see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity

Comment: @gammatester it says it in order notation, I wish to know approximate time for a 2000 bit integer for eg.

Comment: Time for which hardware? What implementation do/will you use? Measure the time for smaller bit numbers on your hardware and extrapolate. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization_records#Numbers_of_a_general_form